# How did the titan that killed Eren's mom appear inside wall Rose during season 2?

Tags: attack-on-titan

During second season (I think is called Clash of the Titans) it's shown that:

> there wasn't a breach in Wall Rose and that those titans that appeared were transformed humans from Connie's town.

How did she get inside Wall Rose then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not mistaken the shifter titans tried to go back to Wall Maria and were some where between wall Maria and Rose,  which was titan territory. [image]

In the picture, you can see how Eren's Liberation was between Wall Maria and Wall Rose.  The smiling titan never passed Wall Rose, all that part was in between Rose and Maria.

Comment: You're right! Don't know how I missed that. Of course It wouldn't make sense that if Eren was captured in Wall Rose, they will run inside again.

Comment: Your welcome. Just click on the answer and place a check mark.  Thanks

Comment: Source for the image?

Answer (score 0):

It did **not**, the entire expedition is set between wall Rose and Maria. Wall rose was still safe and that is where Eren first fought the armored Titan. Even the forest they were headed towards was within wall Maria territory and that's stated in the episode I think by Hanes. furthermore, near the end of the episode, Reiner and the others are shown at the top of what I believe is Wall Maria since the injured including Hanes were at wall Rose.
So the Titan that ate Eres's mom was in wall Maria territory (which is basically where it ate her in the first place), not Rose.